# How do I enable Edit and Continue on a 64-bit application and VB2008 Express?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

When I try to do that I get the following error:

> Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed.

---

@Wilka: That option wasn't available until I selected Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General and check "Show advanced build configurations". Though I found this hint from your MSDN link. So if you edit your comment, I can make it the accepted answer...

Thanks everybody!

---

Please see my first comment on this question, it's not there... Somehow... I can select Target framework though (2.0, 3.0 and 3.5), not that I see any use of that for this particular problem...

---

It doesn't have to be a 64bit program, actually, I rather prefer it to be 32bit anyway since it is more like a utility and it should work on 32bit systems.

Also, I'm running Vista at 64bit. Maybe that has something to do with it?

@Rob Cooper: Now I think of it, I never had the chance of selecting either a 64bit or a 32bit application when creating the solution/project/application...
And according to your link "64-Bit Debugging (X64)" is possible with MS VB2008 express edition.

---

Oh btw, I found the following:

> If you are debugging a 64-bit application and want to use Edit and Continue, you must change the target platform and compile the application as a 32-bit application. You can change this setting by opening the Project Properties and going to the Compile page. On that page, click Advanced Compile Options and change the Target CPU setting to x86 in the Advanced Compiler Settings dialog box. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba77s56w.aspx)

But I dont see the Target CPU setting...

Comment: I have the same problem on "Standard" version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try:

> In Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition: 
>   Build menu  > Configuration Manager...
>
> Change Active solution platform: to
>   "...", choose "x86", save the new
>   platform.
>
> Now the "x86" option is available in
>   the Compile settings.

You may need to enable "Show advanced build configurations" first, in Tools > Options > 
Projects and Solutions > General

(from [this post](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3711099&SiteID=1) on MSDN forums)

Comment: Changing the platform is not the solution in my view.

Comment: Agreed, it does not provide a solution that enables Edit and Continue in a 64-bit solution and could be detrimental to those who intend to write 64-bit apps.

Answer (score 9):

The dialog you're looking for is this one in the project properties:

[image: Platform target]

by default, the target will be "Any CPU" which means it'll run as 64bit on a 64bit OS (like you're using), or 32bit on a 32bit OS - so this wont stop it from working on 32bit systems. But like you said, to use Edit & Continue you will need to target x86 (so it runs as 32bit).

**Edit**: fixed screenshot (I had the C# one, not the VB one)

Comment: If you are debugging, you have to stop before you can change these settings

Answer (score 2):

The "Edit and Continue" feature for 64-bit code will be supported under Visual Studio 2013.

[More information here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK Visual Studio Express does not come with 64bit support.