# How to enable 32-bit build on .NET 2010 Express (no option in ComboBox)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

See Title.  .NET 2010 Express, building a C# Windows Form.

Trying to enable Debug-and-edit, which apparently requires running and building 32-bit applications. 
See question: ["Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed" when debugging in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498464/changes-to-64-bit-applications-are-not-allowed-when-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Fine.  Problem is, my Platform options are limited to (1) "**Active (Any CPU)**" and NOTHING ELSE.

So... Anyone know where THAT setting is hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Build -> Configuration Manager.

The "Active Solution Platform" drop down should have an option for making a new platform.

Or, you can keep the current platform and through project properties -> Build tab select the desired platform target for the current configuration.

Comment: What "Build" root are you talking about?  I don't see one in the Menu Bar.  I've Right-Clicked on my Project through Solution Explorer, then clicked on the Build "Tab" of the vertically stacked tabs.  That's where I got to in the primary question.

Comment: Never mind, found it by right-clicking on Solution through Solution Explorer.  Thanks for the help, never would have thought to try that!