# Using VS 2013 and .net 4.5.1 but still getting “Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed”

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, edit-and-continue

I'm using VS 2013 Ultimate with Update 2 on Win 8.1 x64 and VS won't let me use edit and continue on a simple console application.  The console app is set to use .net 4.5.1 and AnyCPU but whenever I try to change code while debugging I get the dreaded "changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed" message box.

I've tried making sure Edit and Continue is enabled in Tools->Options.  I've tried flipping it off and on again...no good.
I've tried disabling all my VS extensions...didn't make a difference.
I've tried resetting to the default VS settings...nope.
I've tried repairing my VS installation...nothing.
I've tried verifying my .net framework installation...it says my installation is verified but I still have the same problem.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Duplicate of this question...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498464/changes-to-64-bit-applications-are-not-allowed-when-debugging-in-visual-studio Have a look at this site also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/12/how-to-edit-code-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application.aspx

Comment: No, question 1498464 is about VS *2008*.  x64 Edit and Continue was added in VS 2013 but it's not working on my machine.  This is a different question.

Comment: Here is a form from MSDN http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: That's for web sites, this is a console application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My crystal ball says that your debugger is using an older debugging engine.  Another side effect is that you would have never seen [the new method return value debugging feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option.  This option is actually only required to revive C++/CLI debugging.

Comment: You win!  I can't tell you how many hours have been sucked up trying to figure out why this wouldn't work.  I do work with C++/CLI programs so I'll have to keep in mind when to flip that option on or off, but it's nice to (*finally*) have edit and continue working.

Answer (score 0):

Terribly annoying message "Changes not allowed while unmanaged debugging is enabled" and "Changes to 64 bit applications are not allowed". I was successful many times when I tried the following steps:

1. Project Properties >> Debug tab >> UNCHECK "Enable native code debugging"
2. Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> General >> UNCHECK "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"
3. Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> Edit and Continue >> Check Enable Edit and Continue >> UNCHECK Others