# VS.Net 2008 Windows 7 Debug Environment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I'm converting all of my Windows XP production applications to Windows 7 and I am having a couple of problems.

1: Whenever I get an error, on the XP machines, it breaks execution and stops on the line of code with the problem. In Windows 7, it just throws a generic exception and I have no idea where the line of code with the error took place. Very frustrating.

2: In XP, I can edit changes on the fly while I am running code if I place breakpoints or follow along the code. If I try that in Windows 7, it says that's not allowed with 64 bit applications. Again, very frustrating.

Any ideas for fixing these problems or at least working around them?

Comment: This has to be somewhat common, right? No one's seen this?

Comment: Figured out my 2nd question from this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183/how-do-i-enable-edit-and-continue-on-a-64-bit-application-and-vb2008-express

Still stymied on #1. If I create a simple program from scratch, it'll break to the error, but there's something about my large program that's it's not breaking to the specific line of code with the error and rather gives me a generic thrown error message.

Comment: That type of application are you trying to debug? Windows Forms? Web?

Comment: by "generic thrown error message", is there a catch somewhere that is catching the exception you're expecting to break on and throwing a different exception (perhaps wrapping the original exception)?  If so and you want to break on the throwing of the first exception, you need to tell the debugger to do so in "Debug -> Exceptions" dialog.

Comment: @JTew: It's a basic windows exe application with a sub main, modules, and forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference in the debugger's behavior between those two platforms, generally speaking.  Here are my suggestions:

1. From your description, I can't ascertain whether or not the debugger did break on a first chance exception and it didn't find source (perhaps the symbols weren't found / were mismatched?) or if it didn't break at all.  If the former, check "Debug -> Windows -> Modules" and verify that the symbols were loaded for the module in question.  If the latter, perhaps the debugger on Windows XP was configured to break on a first chance exception while the debugger on Windows 7 was not?  Compare the settings under "Debug -> Exceptions" to see if there are any differences.  Note that if you have "Just My Code" enabled in "Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General", this can also affect the breaking behavior of the debugger on first chance exceptions.
2. The Edit and Continue feature is not supported for 64-bit processes, so the debugger will notify you when you attempt to modify the source code when debugging a 64-bit process.  This is likely the result of running an "AnyCPU" (my guess) or "x64" build of your application.  The only way for edit and continue to work is to debug a 32-bit process; this can be accomplished by changing the target platform to "x86" in "Build -> Configuration Manager" (add the platform if it isn't in the list).  This of course assumes your application is not dependent upon 64-bit modules.

Comment: Hey, Peter, thanks for replying with some detailed information to check. I looked at those settings. I AM getting a LOT of errors "Cannot find or open the PDB file." I took a screenshot you can look at here: http://tinyurl.com/5u5kcnt

So, it looks like it's related to not having the right symbols loaded. Why does it work on my XP but not 7.0? Any ideas on what to do to fix it?

Comment: Also, I see there is an option to get the symbols online, but I am using stand-alone workstations without Internet access and I'm not sure if having them online and trying that download would even solve it.

Comment: Some more info: on the machine that WORKS, under the module symbol status, it says: "Skipped loading symbols" ---> http://tinyurl.com/6ywb9o9

So, I'm still not totally sure this is where my problem is located, but it seemed relevant, so I wanted to mention it.

Comment: @Jason: Not being able to find symbols for the .NET Framework modules is to be expected.  The only way to find them is to use Microsoft's public symbol server to download them.  However, I was referring to your particular module (runtest.exe).  The first screenshot is hinting at "Just My Code" (JMC) not being enabled which can affect symbol loading and breaking on first chance exception behavior.  Check the "Enable Just My Code" setting under "Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General" and make sure it matches what is set on the machine that you observe the correct behavior on.

Comment: On the machine that WORKS, which is XP, not Windows 7, the box for "Enable Just my Code" IS checked, but the two boxes beneath it are not.

When I try checking that box on Windows 7, it simply throws the exception and WILL NOT take me to the line of code with the error. When I try UNCHECKING that box, I get an error "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed." and THEN it throws the exception and WILL NOT take me to the line of code with the error.

Comment: @Jason: on the Windows 7 machine, are symbols loading for the module that was built from the source code in question?

Comment: The only one that appears to be loading is the main application "Runtest.exe" where it says "Symbols loaded". under "Symbol Status". Now that I've changed the checkbox to be the same as my Windows XP (which it was originally), I'm getting the same "Skipped loading symbols". All my debugging settings APPEAR to be the same, so I guess I'm back at square 1 unless you can think of something else to look at :(

Comment: As far as that modules window goes, everything looks to be consistent so far with both machines. I just can't get my Windows 7 code to break on the line with the error. IF I start a new application like 'Hello World' and make the same error, it WILL successfully break execution and go to the error like it should. There's just something about this project. I deleted ALL my project files and folders and started from scratch getting it from SourceSafe, but still no dice.

Comment: @Jason: one last thing off the top of my head to check.  Could you right click on the solution node, select "Properties", and then "Debug Source Files" under "Common Properties".  Make sure the source file in question isn't listed under "Do not look for these source files".  This can cause the debugger to treat the source file as not present if the path doesn't exactly match what's in the .pdb.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "common properties". After I right click the solution and properties, my options are application, compile, debug, referencs, resources, services, settings, signing, my extensions, security, and publish. This is on both machines. Sounds like I'm missing something because this page confirms what you said: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdks6de6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Jason: That sounds like the project property pages, not the solution's.  Check that "Always show solution" is checked under "Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General".

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, I had to check that box to get the solution to show up BUT under "Do not look for these source files", there is nothing there. :(

Comment: @Jason: sorry, with the settings the same between the machines and the symbols loading properly for the module containing the source (I assume this is runtest.exe), then I'm at a loss as to why you're not being taken to source on the exception.

Comment: Is there any significance to when I UNCHECK "enable just my code" on my Windows 7 machine, I get a message box "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed." on the line of code with the error and THEN it throws the exception but doesn't take me to the code.

Comment: @Jason: when you look at the call stack when JMC unchecked on the Windows 7 machine, do you see a frame coming from your code?  That is to say, is there a method of yours on the call stack?  If so, could you right click it in the call stack window and select "Symbol Load Information..."?  That might help diagnose why the symbols aren't loading.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but when the error pops up on the Windows 7 machine, it is a RESULT of the code, but NOT coming from the code in terms of an arrow or highlighting. The code is not highlighted. It's a regular message box with buttons to "OK" or "Continue" plus some other links I can click. Here's a screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/3nw56h6 Also, I can create a "Hello World" project from scratch with an error and it WILL successfully break execution with the line of code highlighted on the same Windows 7 machine. Here's a screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/3hdl6bl. What gives? :)

Comment: Well, for one those are entirely different exceptions.  It looks like the type initializer (Sub New() for a module; Sub Shared New() for a class) for Runtest.mMain (I assume this is a module) is throwing an exception before the code you're expecting to throw an exception executes.  Exceptions from type initializers are caught and rethrown as TypeInitializationExceptions.  To break on the exception being thrown in mMain, try checking the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox in the "Debug -> Exceptions" dialog and see which exception you break on then.

Comment: For both cases, the error is the line of code you see highlighted. IF I were to comment out the code, it wouldn't throw an error in either app. HOWEVER, when I checked that box you mentioned, it FINALLY stopped on the line of code highlighted GREEN (not yellow) pointing at it. However, I can't make changes to fix the code on the fly like I'm used to doing as I'm getting a new error about exceptions when I try to edit. Also, in my 'Hello World' program that works highlights the code YELLOW and I CAN make changes to it on the fly. Any ideas? Btw, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Editing code when the debugger breaks on an exception requires the exception to be "unwound".  Is this the new error about exceptions are you seeing?  A green line indicates the code is not from the top most frame in the call stack.  Use "Debug -> Windows -> Callstack" to check the call stack when the exception is thrown.  Which method is first in the list?

Comment: Yes, I did get an "unwound" error. The first method in the list, which has a yellow arrow pointed at it is: mscorlib.dll!System.Number.StringToNumber(string str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, bool parseDecimal) + 0xf7 bytes

To me, that looks like a lower level rendition of the original error.

Comment: With JMC disabled, you're seeing the methods that were called in the Framework in the call stack.  The unwind error is also likely the result of JMC being disabled.  Try turning JMC back on in the debugger options, and go back to the exceptions dialog (Debug -> Exceptions) and check the "Thrown" checkbox next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and see how you fare then.  When JMC is enabled, you should have two checkboxes next to each other: "Thrown" and "User-handled".  When it is off, there should be only "Thrown".

Comment: Not sure if we're fixing it or just making a work around, but we're getting closer nonetheless :) Doing that, I still get a green highlight and I can change the code, BUT it gives me a warning before I do: "The program is currently stopped at an exception ..." and I can Edit, Stop, or Cancel. Any way to suppress that warning and just go straight into Edit mode? Btw the call stack is now: Runtest.exe!Runtest.frmVerbage_NonModal.Verbage_NonModal(String Verbiage = "Error: No Department Identity. Contact Runtest Engineering.", Double Seconds_to_Wait = 2.0) Line 111 + 0xd bytes Basic

Comment: Clicking the "Enable editing" link in the exception assistant should bypass the warning.

Comment: Cool, yeah, when I hit the "enable editing" link that pops up along with everything else, it turns yellow and I can edit. So, any ideas on why I had to do all that and why it just wouldn't work normally? Did we really fix it or just circumvent some big problem? At any rate, that SHOULD allow me to continue with my deployment so I'm very happy about that and many thanks for sticking with me. :D

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head why you wouldn't get the prompt when editing code after breaking on an exception being thrown.  The debugger will always be required to unwind back to the throw for it to reliably make the code change.  If the debugger breaks at something other than a thrown exception (e.g. a breakpoint), then you should be able to modify the code without being prompted in this case.  As far as I can tell from the information you've given me, the debugger won't break on the inner exception by default without you checking the "thrown" checkbox (cont in next comment).

Comment: That is because you're not the one actually handling the exception when it's during type initialization; it's the CLR that's handling the exception and rethrowing it as a different exception.  On a side note, now that you know where the exception is coming from, you can probably uncheck the top-level "thrown" checkbox, otherwise the debugger might break on expected handled exceptions and that may be annoying.

Comment: Ugh, I spoke too soon I guess. I decided to check back on my XP machine to make sure IT still works and now the problem has reversed itself. The same solution that was working on 7 now doesn't work on XP with very similar bad results of not breaking where it should. There's an ADDITIONAL problem, too. All my windows like "properties", "watch", "call stack" pop-out and undock themselves for some reason and I can't get them to dock back. Are XP and 7.0 just not meant to play nicely together? I have 19 workstations and they won't be upgraded all at the same time and I'd like them to coexist. :(

Comment: Well, I always knew where the error was. I intentionally added an error because I noticed errors weren't breaking and wanted to fix that. I'm still confused, though why it was working on XP, wouldn't work on 7, and now won't work on XP again. I'll just keep working through it I guess. Pretty frustrating, though.

Comment: Sadly, this solution won't work for me long term and the reason is what you alluded to in your last explanation. I have many try/catch type code routines and ALL of those trigger a break in an execution of my code when I have the 'thrown' option checked. But, if I DON'T check it on a 7.0 machine, I can't break to the line of code with the error. It's a no win situation. I've spent too much time working on this and have to move on to move on. I'm going to ask to delay deployment indefinitely and maybe come back later with Visual Studio 2010 instead of 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know roughly where the error is coming from?  If so, and not already done, throw a generic try catch around it and break on the catch; then, examine the stack trace to see what line is generating the error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know where the error is coming from. In fact, I specifically added the error myself. My problem is that I can't get the editor to break on the line of code the error happens. That's my "real" error.

Comment: Will the editor break if you set the break on the catch part of a try catch that encompasses the error line?

Comment: No, it won't break on the line of code. That's what concerns me. That's a must have feature and what I'd like to figure out how to fix. I DO want it to break on the line of code I've set an error, not just throw a generic exception and then stop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question. IT WILL BREAK ON THE LINE OF CODE IF I SET A BREAKPOINT. However, once I execute the offending line of code, it won't break back to the line of code as I expect. :)

Comment: Not sure about others, but I think it would be beneficial to see an exmaple of your sample code with comments on where the error is supposed to be.

Comment: The line of code is just an arbitrary one I made up:

Dim i as String = ""
debug.Print(1/i)

I can put a breakpoint on debug.Print(1/i) BUT when I execute it, it won't take me back to the line of code.

If I make a project from scratch that just has one function in Sub Main(), it WILL break to the line of code, but for this larger project I'm converting from XP to 7, the line of code is in different modules and won't break on errors.