# Visual Studio Windows keep undocking

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-xp

I've had a long lengthy problem with something else and in trying to fix that, I've created a new problem.

If you want the back story to my original problem, read this thread: [VS.Net 2008 Windows 7 Debug Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424246/vs-net-2008-windows-7-debug-environment)

My NEW problem is that when I execute my code, all my windows pop-out and undock themselves. I can drag them back to their original positions, but every time I run the code, they undock themselves again. EVERY window like "watch 1", "watch 2", "watch 3", "watch 4", "call stack", and MANY others. The solution explorer and properties just disappear alltogether. I'm trying to get a project base to play nicely in XP and 7.0 and THIS is one of the results I'm getting.

Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that the problem I'm having NOW is on the Windows XP machine. It wasn't undocking on 7.0.

Comment: Btw, here's a photo: http://tinyurl.com/3e6y79k

Does that EVERY time even after I reset them.

Comment: The window layout for debug mode is stored separately.  In the menu: Windows + Reset Window Layout while debugging.

Comment: I think I tried that before. It doesn't help it. I've selected that while debugging and while not debugging. Every time the windows pop up undocked and solution explorer just disappears. In the SAME session I can reset them and they will STILL do the same thing over and over. I'm going to try to uninstall and reinstall and see what happens.

Comment: Delete the hidden .suo file in the solution directory before you make drastic moves like this.

Comment: +1, I am facing a similar issue with VC (VS 2008). Really annoying.